# How to get everything within brackets in golang with regex

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to get everything within the outside brackets of the following sql statement in golang regular expressions.

```
Categories
(// = outside bracket
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)//=outside bracket
```

how would I use regex to only identify the outer brackets and return everything in between the outside brackets?

Comment: Maybe `\`(?s)\((.*)\)\`` is all you need.

Comment: thanks it worked, how would you now remove the outer brackets `[( ... )]`

Comment: Why remove them? Just access the first submatch.

Comment: Makes sense , thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is to find the first `(`, then match any characters up to the last `)` with

```
`(?s)\((.*)\)`
```

**Details**:

- `(?s)` - allow `.` to match any character, including a newline
- `\(` -  a literal `(` char
- `(.*)` - Submatch 1 capturing any zero or more characters
- `\)` - a literal `)` symbol.

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/GLTxOv5ck2):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := `Categories
(// = outside bracket
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)//=outside bracket`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?s)\((.*)\)`)

    m := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(s,-1)
    fmt.Printf("Capture value: %s", m[0][1])
}
```